# Matching characters in strings

Tags: python, string

I have 2 `lists` of `strings`:

```
list1 = ['GERMANY','FRANCE','SPAIN','PORTUAL','UK']

list2 = ['ERMANY','FRANCE','SPAN','PORTUGAL','K']
```

I wanted to obtain a `list` where only the respective `strings` with 1 character less are shown. i.e:

```
final_list = ['ERMANY','SPAN','K']
```

What's the best way to do it? Using regular expressions?

Thanks

Comment: Is 'PORTUAL' a spelling error, or should it be that way?

Comment: Spelling error, sorry !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
list1 = ['GERMANY','FRANCE','SPAIN','PORTUGAL','UK']

list2 = ['ERMANY','FRANCE','SPAN','PORTUGAL','K']


new = [a for a, b in zip(list2, list1) if len(a) < len(b)]
```

Comment: Glad I could help!